# Get values from elements inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get values inside div on clicking a button, wich locates inside this div. Here is the html structure:

```
<div class="products__item">
  <div class="products__content">
    <a class="products__title" href="#">Altec Lansing Octiv Duo M202 акустическая система акустическая система</a>
    <div class="products__priceholder">
      <p class="products__price"><strong>86 590</strong> руб.</p>
      <small class="products__id">ID. 10906</small>
      </div>
      <p class="exist">В наличии</p>
      <div class="products__buttonholder">
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="buyModal" class="button button-buy-modal">Купить</a>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I click on .button-buy-modal, I need to get values from .products__title .products__price and .products__id, but the problem is that we have a lot same div's (product cards), and a lot of buttons inside them. I think that I should use something like $(this), but actually I don't know how.

I'm trying to test something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("a.button-buy-modal").click(function () {
    $(this).find().closest('.products__priceholder').addClass('test1');
})
```

Here is a solution:

```
$("a.button-buy-modal").click(function () {
var prTitle = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__title').html();
var prPrice = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__priceholder').children('.products__price').children('strong').html();
var prId = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__priceholder').children('.products__id').html();
var prImage = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.products__imageholder').children('.products__thumbnail').attr('src');
console.log(prTitle);
console.log(prPrice);
console.log(prId);
console.log(prImage);
```

})

Comment: you should use $(this) and parent properties.

Comment: And where is your jQuery code? What have you tried? Have you searched for an answer on a similar question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.products__price').text()
```

will give you  this - `"86 590 руб."`

```
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.products__price').html()
```

will give you this -- `"<strong>86 590</strong> руб."`

To learn more about it as in how you can select any particular DOM element and read it or manipulate it etc, read here - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Read again the question please. A suggestion about using the `.closest()` method would be actually more useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to your parent div or use eq(x) to select the right group.

```
<div id="mydiv1" class="products__item">
  <div class="products__content">
    <a class="products__title" href="#">Altec Lansing Octiv Duo M202 акустическая система акустическая система</a>
    <div class="products__priceholder">
      <p class="products__price"><strong>86 590</strong> руб.</p>
      <small class="products__id">ID. 10906</small>
      </div>
      <p class="exist">В наличии</p>
      <div class="products__buttonholder">
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="buyModal" class="button button-buy-modal">Купить</a>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
var title = $('#div1 .products__title').html();
/// OR
var title = $('.products__item:eq(0) .products__title').html();

var price = $('#div1 .products__price').html();
/// OR
var price = $('.products__item:eq(0) .products__price').html();

price = price.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // regex to remove tags
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use .closest(), you don't need .find()

```
$("a.button-buy-modal").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.products__priceholder').addClass('test1');
});
```

Comment: first approach is not very scalable for repeating rows as OP mentioned. Dynamic ID's are more of a headache than just using simple traverese

Answer (score 0):

Thank's all for advices, I found a solution:

```
    $("a.button-buy-modal").click(function () {
    var prTitle = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__title').html();
    var prPrice = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__priceholder').children('.products__price').children('strong').html();
    var prId = $(this).parent().parent().children('.products__priceholder').children('.products__id').html();
    var prImage = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.products__imageholder').children('.products__thumbnail').attr('src');
    console.log(prTitle);
    console.log(prPrice);
    console.log(prId);
    console.log(prImage);
})
```